# Asp MVC how refresh index page after data deletion

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

in ASP MVC 5 i have a table with delete button on each rows. When i click on the "Delete" button i show a modal confirmation (bootstrap) dialog: if the user confirm the deletion i call the following javascript function:

```
function confirmedDeletion(){
    $.post("@Url.Action("Delete", "MyController")", { id : id } , function (data) {
    });
}
```

So is called the Delete Action in the controller:

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
{
    ...
    ...
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

The Index action is called and executed but the html page is not refreshed (the modal dialog remains visible and the table data aren't updated. The browser doesn't show the icon of refreshing the page)

How can i reload the index page?

Comment: Did you check your browser's JavaScript console for errors?

Comment: No error...maybe the browser doesn't know that it must refresh the page because i execute an ajax request?

Comment: The point of AJAX is to avoid a page refresh. Instead of doing a refresh, why don't you make another AJAX call to retrieve the updated data?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot respond to the ajax call with a redirect. You can reload the page in the ajax callback function with a javascript:

```
function confirmedDeletion(){
    $.post("@Url.Action("Delete", "MyController")", { id : id } , function (data) {
        if(data.Success) {
            window.location.reload();
        }
    });
}

[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
{
    ...
    ...
    db.SaveChanges();
    return Json(new { Success = true; });
}
```

As an alternative to the refreshing the page you could remove the deleted row from the table:

```
function confirmedDeletion($button){
    $.post("@Url.Action("Delete", "MyController")", { id : id } , function (data) {
        if(data.Success) {
            $button.closest('tr').remove();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the row after a successfull call (as in Zabravsky's answer) seems like the cleanest answer. But if you want to refresh the entire page after your delete call, it seems you shouldn't be using Ajax, you should just submit the form directly.

Comment: Point taken- edited the answer to rephrase my question as the solution.